# Cannot find module 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'

Tags: typescript, mapbox-gl-js

I am getting an error when trying to import mapboxgl into my TypeScript file.

I've done it like in the [README](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js#using-mapbox-gl-js-with-other-module-systems) for mapbox-gl-js:

`import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';`

Then when I run the typescript compiler:

```
tsc
```

I receive this error:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'.`

But for some reason, everything still gets compiled and works fine. So I am confused what this actual means?

I have created an issue for this on Github: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this issue by using this import instead:

`import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';`

But not all is fixed by this. I'm using Rollup for bundling and this has now caused an error:

```
Illegal reassignment to import 'mapboxgl'
Error: Illegal reassignment to import 'mapboxgl'
at error (C:\Users\m.wilson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\src\utils\error.js:2:14)
at disallowIllegalReassignment (C:\Users\m.wilson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rollup\src\ast\nodes\shared\disallowIllegalReassignment.js:9:4)
```

Comment: See this answer on how to get around the Rollup error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41118458/2393347

Answer (score 0):

`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'`

The `mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js` file is a build file which is not checked into git. It is included with the `npm` package. If you are missing this file, you may generate it by running `npm install && npm run build-min` in the `mapbox-gl` folder.

Comment: I'm not missing the file, I think the main reason this error occurs is due to TypeScript not detecting its a module.

Comment: If you see my answer below, I instead used the main script in npm and was able to import via ```import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';```, but this is now causing an error with the rollup bundler

Answer (score 0):

Yes your right.
To declare (like for most external js libraries):
from the root of your folder (you may have to use sudo for npm install).

```
$ npm install -g typings;
$ typings install --save --global dt~geojson
$ typings install --save --global dt~mapbox-gl
```

PS: I'm working on this also. I can serve and build but on android-simulation i get a black screen.
Could you right how it is for you it would be nice

Comment: ```import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';``` will stop this error and I didn't need to install typings for it. But the downside is that when using the Rollup bundler, this error is outputted ```Error: Illegal reassignment to import 'mapboxgl'```

Comment: or maybe this: npm install --save @types/mapbox-gl

Comment: because this: npm install --save @types/mapbox-gl

Answer (score 0):

This might be against all things holy, but I did get things to work by importing like so...

`const mapboxgl = require('../../../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');`
`const Map = mapboxgl.Map`